# How to dynamically change page title and description in ClojureScript / Reagent

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, isomorphic-javascript, reagent

Is there a simple way to change document title and description (or other `[:html [:head [:meta` tags) from ClojureScript Reagent application? For example on every `bidi` route match change the title and description to match the new page content.

Preferably this should work without using `js/window` so that the same code can be used in a browser as well as in server isomorphic pre-rendering (which I need for SEO).

In the JavaScript/React world there are [react-document-meta](https://github.com/kodyl/react-document-meta) and [react-side-effect](https://github.com/gaearon/react-side-effect) which can probably be converted to Reagent components. But this way of handling side effects seems like a hack and probably simpler solution can be done in pure ClojureScript.

Comment: I found a related question that tries to solve the same problem using import of npm react-helmet module. But fails to compile the result and no working answer is found yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272447/reagent-adapt-react-class-fails-with-optimizations-advanced

Answer (score 2):

I'm not using `bidi`, but a similar bidirectional router `silk` together with `re-frame`. For every page change, we trigger a `:set-current-route` event which will be handled centrally.

The handler for `:set-current-route` will then

```
(set! (.-title js/document) "dynamic title")
```

Comment: This works in browser. But when compiled :target :nodejs and run on node or other non-browser environment, it fails because js/document is not available. So it does not solve the SEO and isomorfic part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am also not using `bidi`, but here is the solution I came up with for updating the HTML document title using `reitit` in `reagent`. I call this function from my main route-wrapping component's `:component-did-update`:

```clj
(defn update-html-title! []
  (set! (.-title js/document)
        (->> (.. js/window -location -pathname)
             (rf/match-by-path router)
             :data
             :title)))
```