# reagent/adapt-react-class fails with :optimizations :advanced

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, reagent

I'm importing a [react component](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) (using the :npm-deps support) and wrapping with the adapt-react-class adapter:

```
(:require [reagent.core :as reagent]
          [react-helmet]) 

(def meta-tags* (reagent/adapt-react-class (aget react-helmet "default")))

(defn main-panel []
  (let []
    (fn []
      [meta-tags*])))
```

This works fine for development, but when advanced compiler is on:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

Minimimal repo:
https://github.com/fbielejec/npm-deps-demo

Comment: I hope solution to this would eventually solve this previous question of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44975192/how-to-dynamically-change-page-title-and-description-in-clojurescript-reagent/44991056

Answer (score 0):

`meta-tags*` is a class, but you're trying to call it like a function by placing it inside the Reagent square braces i.e. `meta-tags*`.

In the source code that you posted on GitHub, you also define a function called `meta-tags`. It looks like you're accidentally calling `meta-tags*` by mistake. Your full code (based on the Github demo) should read:

```
(ns app.views
  (:require [reagent.core :as reagent]
            [react-helmet]))

(def meta-tags* (reagent/adapt-react-class (aget react-helmet "default")))

(defn meta-tags [{:keys [:title :description]
                  :or {title "Some title"
                       description "some description"}}]
  [meta-tags* {:id "app-meta-tags"}
   [:title {:id "title" :title title}]
   [:meta {:id "description" :content description}]])

(defn main-panel []
  (let []
    (fn []
      [:div.container
       [meta-tags] ; <- no * star!
       [:h1 "Check for the meta-tags presence"]])))
```

Comment: Him thanks you for answering. I don't think this makes any dfference, the meta-tags function is just a wrapper around the adapted component. I just simplified the code snippet for the sake of brewity. The github code is 1-1 to what you pasted here.

Comment: I tried further simplifying the minimal repo even more to https://github.com/VaclavSynacek/npm-deps-demo but still cannot get it to work. The trouble with `met-tags*` and `meta-tags` that Scott suggests are the problem are factored our, but still no working result.